# How to config adv7180 video decoder through I2c?

Tags: verilog, fpga, i2c

I have de2-115 board "based on **FPGA**" and analog camera **"NTSC standard"** connected to it .
In this de2-115 board there is a chip called adv7180 which convert analog signal to digital signal **"YCbCr 4:2:2 format"**,to do that I have to config adv7180 registers through I2c protocol **in Verilog**
here you could find every information about [adv7180 chip](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADV7180.pdf)
for more information about [adv7180 pin assignments in de2 board](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~courses/ee8205/Data-Sheets/DE2-Board/Altera-DE2-115-User_Manual.pdf) 
so which **"0x40,subaddress,data"** should I send to get correct output?

Answer (score 0):

For which registers to write and what to write to them, you're going to have to read the datasheet and perhaps do some experimenting.

For how to write them in Verilog, you'll need an I2C master and something to drive it with.  If you have a soft core or on-FPGA CPU or some sort of control path from a PC (USB, serial port, Ethernet, etc.) then bridging this to the I2C bus would be the simplest thing to do.  Otherwise, you'll probably want some sort of state machine which can perform the necessary I2C initalization operations on power-up.

I have a generic I2C board init module here: https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-i2c/blob/master/rtl/i2c_init.v .  This module is intended to perform a set of I2C write operations to one or more slave devices on power-up to initialize support peripherals such as oscillators, PLLs, clock distribution, and interface components.  It is designed to be paired with this I2C master module: https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-i2c/blob/master/rtl/i2c_master.v .